# senderscore.org reports volume 15 time higher then what we actually send

Tags: email

We've encountered a problem with low score (it's actually zero now!) in senderscore.org and as a consequence our service provider want to termintate our service. According to postfix logs, we send about 700 emails daily on average from our server. senderscore.org says it's about 10000.

We have SPF, DKIM and DMARC all set up and tested to reject any email send not from our domain (avia.lt). It doesn't help, the volume actually went up a bit.

Why the volume is so high in senderscore.org and what do we do to improve our score?

Comment: Counting the same thing over the matching time frame (unique messages, or attempts to relay one or more messages, or total recipients)? Any subdomains opting out of your 2nd-level policies?

Comment: Senderscore only says "volume", no more information. The volume/score is for a the IP address, not domain/subdomain.

Comment: And in the server we used pflogsumm to determine the number of delivered message in a day:

    467   received
    468   delivered
      2   forwarded
     60   deferred  (1088  deferrals)
     18   bounced
      8   rejected (1%)

Comment: I mean 1k messages is not much, why not using it as opportunities to migrate?